# How to show display device names in xrandr?

Tags: xrandr

My `Xorg.0.log` contains display device names like `DFP-0`.
`xrandr` shows output names like `HDMI-0`.

Can `xrandr` also show the "display devices names"?

Comment: On my system these provide consistent output. Please provide OS vendor and version, Xorg and xrandr versions, example lines from `Xorg.0.log` and `xrandr` output. Detail your expectations and the problem with result you got.

Comment: @FerencWágner I would like to list the "display devices names" using xrandr. I tried several options but it did not give me the names. Perhaps it isn't possible? Preferably the answer is independent of Xorg, OS and xrandr version (except for a minimum version).

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is answered on [askubuntu.com: Display monitor info via command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371261/display-monitor-info-via-command-line). I copy&paste the essential part here:

If you have ubuntu just install the read-edid package (on other Linux systems you have to figure out which package contains the get-edid, parse-edid commands):

```
    sudo apt install read-edid
```

Then you can use the following command to get the name of your monitors:

```
    sudo get-edid  | parse-edid
```

In the output you will see (among other info) something like this:

```
    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "DELL U2412M"
        ModelName "DELL U2412M"
        VendorName "DEL"
```

ps: this detection based on [EDID (Extended Display Identification Data)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)